# How to color a clicked bar from barchart with r, plolty, shiny when having already event_data("plotly_click")

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I am trying to understand how `event_data()` works by recreating an example from **Interactive web-based data visualization with r plotly and shiny**, chapter **Linking views with shiny**:
https://plotly-r.com/linking-views-with-shiny.html#fig:plotlyEvents so I could color the bar that has been selected. 
First when I run the code I get:

*"Warning: The 'plotly_click' event tied a source ID of 'sub_category' is not registered. In order to obtain this event data, please add `event_register(p, 'plotly_click')` to the plot (`p`) that you wish to obtain event data from.
Warning: The 'plotly_click' event tied a source ID of 'order_date' is not registered. In order to obtain this event data, please add `event_register(p, 'plotly_click')` to the plot (`p`) that you wish to obtain event data from.
Warning: The 'plotly_click' event tied a source ID of 'sub_category' is not registered. In order to obtain this event data, please add `event_register(p, 'plotly_click')` to the plot (`p`) that you wish to obtain event data from.
Warning: The 'plotly_click' event tied a source ID of 'order_date' is not registered. In order to obtain this event data, please add `event_register(p, 'plotly_click')` to the plot (`p`) that you wish to obtain event data from."*

then I read about `event_register()` I am trying to modify the code, but apart from breaking it, I don't achieve much. 
I also experiment with `highlight()` to color the clicked bar but I guess I don't use it correctly in this example, because again, the code breaks. Would you please give me some enlightenment on how to color the bars that were selected and the subcategory to have the same color. Thank you very much for your time!

[image]

```
  library(shiny)
  library(plotly)
  library(dplyr)


  sales <- diamonds
  sales$category = sales$cut
  sales$sub_category = sales$color
  sales$sales = sales$price
  sales$order_date = sample(seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), as.Date('2020-02-01'), by="day"),nrow(sales), replace = T)



  ui <- fluidPage(
    plotlyOutput("category", height = 200),
    plotlyOutput("sub_category", height = 200),
    plotlyOutput("sales", height = 300),
    DT::dataTableOutput("datatable")
  )

  # avoid repeating this code
  axis_titles <- . %>%
    layout(
      xaxis = list(title = ""),
      yaxis = list(title = "Sales")
    )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {

    # for maintaining the state of drill-down variables
    category <- reactiveVal()
    sub_category <- reactiveVal()
    order_date <- reactiveVal()

    # when clicking on a category, 
    observeEvent(event_data("plotly_click", source = "category"), {
      category(event_data("plotly_click", source = "category")$x)
      sub_category(NULL)
      order_date(NULL)
    })

    observeEvent(event_data("plotly_click", source = "sub_category"), {
      sub_category(
        event_data("plotly_click", source = "sub_category")$x
      )
      order_date(NULL)
    })

    observeEvent(event_data("plotly_click", source = "order_date"), {
      order_date(event_data("plotly_click", source = "order_date")$x)
    })

    output$category <- renderPlotly({
      sales %>%
        count(category, wt = sales) %>%
        plot_ly(x = ~category, y = ~n, source = "category") %>%
        axis_titles() %>% 
        layout(title = "Sales by category")
    })

    output$sub_category <- renderPlotly({
      if (is.null(category())) return(NULL)

      sales %>%
        filter(category %in% category()) %>%
        count(sub_category, wt = sales) %>%
        plot_ly(x = ~sub_category, y = ~n, source = "sub_category") %>%
        axis_titles() %>%
        layout(title = category())
    })

    output$sales <- renderPlotly({
      if (is.null(sub_category())) return(NULL)

      sales %>%
        filter(sub_category %in% sub_category()) %>%
        count(order_date, wt = sales) %>%
        plot_ly(x = ~order_date, y = ~n, source = "order_date") %>%
        add_lines() %>%
        axis_titles() %>%
        layout(title = paste(sub_category(), "sales over time"))
    })

    output$datatable <-  DT::renderDataTable({
      if (is.null(order_date())) return(NULL)

      sales %>%
        filter(
          sub_category %in% sub_category(),
          as.Date(order_date) %in% as.Date(order_date())
        )
    })

  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go mate, I just added the colours based on your what was clicked.
The line plot was green by default, so we don't need to worry about it.
For the first plot I will mutate red color if a category() is clicked. For some reason I was unable to mutate it directly, so I created a plot_data before the plot and had if else statements to do so (nested if_else did not work)
For the second plot I will mutate green color if sub_category() is clicked.

Hope this is what you're looking for!

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)


sales <- diamonds
sales$category = sales$cut
sales$sub_category = sales$color
sales$sales = sales$price
sales$order_date = sample(seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), as.Date('2020-02-01'), by="day"),nrow(sales), replace = T)



ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("category", height = 200),
  plotlyOutput("sub_category", height = 200),
  plotlyOutput("sales", height = 300),
  DT::dataTableOutput("datatable")
)

# avoid repeating this code
axis_titles <- . %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = list(title = ""),
    yaxis = list(title = "Sales")
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # for maintaining the state of drill-down variables
  category <- reactiveVal()
  sub_category <- reactiveVal()
  order_date <- reactiveVal()

  # when clicking on a category, 
  observeEvent(event_data("plotly_click", source = "category"), {
    category(event_data("plotly_click", source = "category")$x)
    sub_category(NULL)
    order_date(NULL)
  })

  observeEvent(event_data("plotly_click", source = "sub_category"), {
    sub_category(
      event_data("plotly_click", source = "sub_category")$x
    )
    order_date(NULL)
  })

  observeEvent(event_data("plotly_click", source = "order_date"), {
    order_date(event_data("plotly_click", source = "order_date")$x)
  })

  output$category <- renderPlotly({
    print(category())
    if (is.null(category())) {
      plot_data <- sales %>%
        count(category, wt = sales) %>%
        mutate(current_color = "blue")
    } else {
      plot_data <- sales %>%
        count(category, wt = sales) %>%
        mutate(current_color = if_else(category %in% category(), "red", "blue"))
    }
      plot_ly(
        plot_data, x = ~category, y = ~n, source = "category", type = "bar",
              marker = list(color = ~current_color)
      ) %>%
      axis_titles() %>% 
      layout(title = "Sales by category")
  })

  output$sub_category <- renderPlotly({
    if (is.null(category())) return(NULL)
    sales %>%
      filter(category %in% category()) %>%
      count(sub_category, wt = sales) %>%
      mutate(current_color = if_else(sub_category %in% sub_category(), "green", "red")) %>%
      plot_ly(
        x = ~sub_category, y = ~n, source = "sub_category", type = "bar",
        marker = list(color = ~current_color)
      ) %>%
      axis_titles() %>%
      layout(title = category())
  })

  output$sales <- renderPlotly({
    if (is.null(sub_category())) return(NULL)
    sales %>%
      filter(sub_category %in% sub_category()) %>%
      count(order_date, wt = sales) %>%
      plot_ly(x = ~order_date, y = ~n, source = "order_date", line = list(color = "green")) %>%
      add_lines() %>%
      axis_titles() %>%
      layout(title = paste(sub_category(), "sales over time"))
  })

  output$datatable <-  DT::renderDataTable({
    if (is.null(order_date())) return(NULL)

    sales %>%
      filter(
        sub_category %in% sub_category(),
        as.Date(order_date) %in% as.Date(order_date())
      )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: wow! that's amazing! Thank you very much! I was thinking that the solution is hidden somewhere in this `event_data()`, and yet - not necessarily. Your approach is super, Thank you very much!